# Difference between for items in list and for i in range (0, len(x)) in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, difference

I'm getting to grips with lists in python but I'm stumped when it comes to the difference in using these two functions.

```
def print_list(x):
    for j in range (0, len(x)):
        print x[j]
```

and

```
def print_list(x):
    for item in list:
        j = 0
        print x[j]
        j++
```

Can anyone explain to a beginner? Thanks!

Comment: The second one doesn't seems to be a valid Python syntax; `j++` must be `j+=1` and that `j=0` initialization must be outside the loop.

Comment: Also, there is no `list` variable in the second, so the `for` loop will crash (unless a variable `list` was created elsewhere). You should make sure your code at least **runs** before you ask a question about it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume

```
def print_list(x):
    for j in range (0, len(x)):
         print x[j]
```

is how loops run in C++. So you understand that intuitively. Here, `range` generates (look up [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)) the values `0` through `len(x)` and the `for` statement iterates through them.

Your 2nd syntax, as pointed out in the comments, is wrong. I assume you meant

```
def print_list(x):
    for item in x:
        print(item)
```

The `for` statement iterates through every `item` in the list `x`.
So if your list is `[1,3,5,7,9]`, in the 1st loop, `item` will have value `1`. In the 2nd loop, `item` will have the value `3`. In the 3rd loop, `item` will have the value `5`. And so on.

When all the values have been iterated through, the `for` loop ends.

Comment: Thanks, marked your answer as correct. Apologies for lack of knowledge I'm just starting out in python (three days to be exact haha)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being a beginner. Everybody has to start somewhere. Its just that we appreciate it if you go through the docs first, try to understand what is wrong and present a strong question. Cheers and all the best.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is correct and it should be pythonic enough. The second one is incorrect.

```
def print_list(x):
    for item in list: #where is the iterable oject called list? This shuold be x
        j = 0 # if you use a counter like j you shuold be defining before the loop otherwise you keep resetting it to 0.
        print x[j]
        j++
```

A more pythonic and better way if you want to print all the elemets in a list interating over them.

```
def print_list(list_item):
    for element in list_item:
         print(element)
```

You don't need to use the range and len like in the first example, list are iterable object so you can just do like the above example without recuring to range().

Comment: One more thing that is wrong with the second one: `j++` is invalid syntax.  It should be `j += 1`.